# Create order with coupon lines using WooCommerce Rest API

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, woocommerce-rest-api, coupon

We are trying to create an order and apply a coupon code using woo commerce API as explained in the woo commerce documentation. following is the JSON we are trying to send with the API request.

```
{
"order":{
"payment_details":{"method_id":"cash","method_title":"cash","paid":false},
"billing_address":{"first_name":"kamran","last_name":"masud","company":null,"address_1":"Dubai Dubai - United Arab Emirates",
    "address_2":null,"city":null,"state":null,"postcode":null,"country":null,"email":null,"phone":"541234566"},
"shipping_address":{"first_name":"kamran","last_name":"masud","company":null,"address_1":"Dubai Dubai - United Arab Emirates",
"address_2":null,"city":null,"state":null,"postcode":null,"country":null},
"customer_id":116,
"line_items":[
    {"product_id":11734,"variation_id":0,"quantity":108,"total":"3834"},
    {"product_id":10893,"variation_id":0,"quantity":1,"total":"206.56"},
    {"product_id":11872,"variation_id":0,"quantity":1,"total":"41.49"},
    {"product_id":11866,"variation_id":0,"quantity":1,"total":"53.17"},
    {"product_id":11865,"variation_id":0,"quantity":1,"total":"53.17"},
    {"product_id":11965,"variation_id":0,"quantity":1,"total":"47.81"},
    {"product_id":11626,"variation_id":0,"quantity":1,"total":"323.73"},
    {"product_id":11927,"variation_id":0,"quantity":1,"total":"144.3"}],
"shipping_lines":[],
"fee_lines":[
    {"id":0,"title":"Shipping :","tax_class":null,"total":"0","total_tax":null}
    ],
"coupon_lines":[
    {
    "code":"fixedcart10",
    "discount":"80",
    "meta_data":[
        {
            "key":"coupon_data",
            "value":[
            {
                "id":"168026",
                "code":"fixedcart10",
                "amount":"10"
            }
            ]
        }
    ]
    }
],
"discount_total":null,
"shipping_total":null,
"total":null,"status":"processing"}}
```

coupon goes through with the order it doesn't get applied in the created order. following is the screenshot of the order created.
[image]

Any help would be appreciated.
thanks

Answer (score 0):

I think because you are manually passing on the 'total' value it overrides the automatic calculation that WooCommerce usually applies for coupons.  If you only pass product_id, variation_id and quantity it should be fine.

It gets a bit more problematic if you are updating line_items on a WooCommerce order, however, as discounts are calculated from the sub_total (pre-discount) and total (after discount) values that are passed when updating.